# Compression program gives StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, compression

I am trying to write a compression program that removes vowels, using a String instead of an array, per the assignment specifications, but I keep getting this error. I am totally lost. Could use some help.

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

```
static String stringCompress(String msg) {

    String vowels = VOWELS;
    String output = "";
    String localChar;

   for (int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++) {
       localChar = String.valueOf(msg.charAt(i));
       if (!VOWELS.contains(localChar)|| Character.isWhitespace(msg.charAt(i-1))){
           output += localChar;

       }
   }
    return output;
```

Comment: If you do `msg.charAt(i-1)` when `i` is zero, that is what happens.

Comment: Maybe you could keep only non-vowels?

Comment: try to catch your error on the line of java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0):

```
Solved

String output = "";
        String localChar;
        if(msg.isEmpty()) {
            output = "";
            return output;
        }
        output = String.valueOf(msg.charAt(0));
       for (int i = 1; i <= msg.length()-1; i++) {
           localChar = String.valueOf(msg.charAt(i));
           if (!VOWELS.contains(localChar)|| Character.isWhitespace(msg.charAt(i-1))){
               output += localChar;

           }
       }
```